# Decompose into microservice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

I have the below requirement

1)Fetch data from Oracle databse
2)Send the fetch data to Rabbit MQ
3) Log the messages in Mongo DB

Current i  have a single spring boot app for performing all the operation.Is this the correct architecture for microservices?Or should I decompose into  MULTIPLE small microservices.Kindly provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the microservices architecture implies dividing a monolith into more manageable services. Those services should be independent and loosely coupled.

In your particular use case, the services you describe would not be loosely coupled, and it would be hard to find usages for one without the other.

That being said, I would propose you use a single application with multiple instances, for better scalability. Here's what I suggest:

1. Each instance fetches data from the Oracle Database and sends it to a specific RabbitMQ queue. You would have to divide the data into disjunct chunks.
2. Each instance consumes from one queue and logs the messages into Mongo DB.

This way, the load can be balanced among instances and also, by using some concurrency mechanism (such as a thread pool) for each task (1 and 2 from above), you could easily configure to use more threads for the task that you believe requires more resources.

Comment: well this one just one app.for eg i will be creating 10 different apps which will interact with both oracle and mongo db.And they wil have different use cases and not necessarily use Rabbitmq eg.displaying data to user.So i need to design keeping this in mind

Comment: I understand. What you should remember still, is that the features you describe are still not independent enough for it to be worth splitting into microservices. You can split them functionally and have a way to scale them individually in the way I described. Each such app can be designed this way, such that each granular task it performs can be scaled.